# When do I need to use beforeEach block in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I just started learning unit testing using Jasmine. I have gone through the [official documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html?) of jasmine and searched a lot over stackoverflow. Please see the below code.

```
describe('calculator', function () {
  var calculator;
  beforeEach( function(){
    calculator = new myApp.Calculator();
  });

  describe('sum', function () {
    it('1 + 1 should equal 2', function () {
        expect(calculator.add(1, 1)).toBe(2);
    }); 
  });

  describe('subtract', function () {
    it('3 - 2 should equal 1', function () {
        expect(calculator.subtract(3, 2)).toBe(1);
    });
  });

});
```

Here I have initialized/created the instance of Calculator in the `beforeEach` block. It also works fine if I write it directly inside the first `describe` block without using the `beforeEach` block.

I understand the user of `beforeEach` and `afterEach`. But here in this case(or for any such cases) do I really need to use `beforeEach` where no one is updating the `Calculator` instance, in each spec we are just using the methods of `calculator`? If I use `beforeEach`, it will create new instance everytime before each test. But why do I need a new instance always where none of my testcase is not going to change/ update my instance?

Comment: And what will you do when your tests start producing different results when run singled out rather than in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

If you will put line of code to create instance of Calculator in the `describe` directly without using the `beforeEach` In that case the instance will be created one time only(at the start of test cases run).
But if you will put in `beforeEach` block, In that case the new instance will be created for each single test case run, so every test case will have a fresh new instance.

And it is good practice to have a fresh instance for each particular test case. Because it is thumb rule that a test case should never depend on another test case. And test case should always run in in-dependent order.

Comment: That's exactly my query. Why do I need a new instance always if none of my testcase is not dependent on another or none of testcase updates the calculator instance? And I'am not maintaining any state here. Can you give any example where it would fail or misbehave!

Comment: Yes, it is fine with your current scenario, but it is not a good practice because if someone other jumps on your code later on and they start writing new test cases which depend on Instance, In that case, it will be a situation where it fails.